# Current row index in table

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

How do you get the current row in a table?

I have tried:

This returns the worksheet row

```
=ROW([@[Column1]])
```

This:

```
=Table1[[#This Row],[Column1]]
```

gets transformed into:

```
=Table[@Column1]
```

and simply returns `0`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work in all columns no matter where your table is on the spreadsheet, assuming your table is named Table1.

```
=ROW()-ROW(Table1)+1
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried Michael's solution and found out that newer version requires excel's implicit intersection notation like the following.

```
=ROW()-@ROW(table_name)+1
```